# EXCEL - Array based on cell value

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an issue with my EXCEL Macro, and I hope some of you will be able to assist me figuring out what has gone wrong.

Now, the macro consists of some mix-matching I've found around the interwebs.

Basically, when stood in the Active Workbook, I want to edit values in 'MACROTEST.xlsm', then create a new Workbook based on some om MACROTESTS's current Sheets.
The Sheets I want in the newly created Workbook are mentioned in the active workbook cell "I2" example of I2: ("FRONTPAGE" , "AT" , "BY" , "BE") - Yes the cell contains the quotation marks as well. - Not the ()

For some reason I can't get my array to pick up these values, help..

Also for some reason, when I run the macro a new workbook with 1 sheet is opened. - Can't figure out what causes this.

I'm a rookie EXCEL coder, so please go easy on me when you bash my coding :)

```
Sub NewReport()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim WbC As Workbook
Dim dateStr As String
Dim myDate As Date

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set WbC = ActiveWorkbook
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("J:\Documents\Test\New\MACROTEST.xlsm")

Set CH = WbC.Sheets("MAIN")
Set sh = Wb1.Sheets("FRONTPAGE")
sh.Range("D2") = CH.Range("C4")

Set upd = CH.Range("I2")

myDate = Date

dateStr = Format(myDate, "DD-MM-YY")

Set Wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Wb1.Sheets(Array(upd)).Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)
Wb2.Sheets(Wb2.Sheets.Count).Delete
Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="J:\Documents\Test\New\" & Sheets("FRONTPAGE").Range("D2").Value & " " & dateStr, FileFormat:=51

Wb2.Close
Wb1.Close
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Set Wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Wb1.Sheets(Array(upd)).Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)
```

By:

```
Dim sheetName As Variant
Set Wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add 'This line will open a new workbook

For Each sheetName In Split(Replace(CH.Range("I2"), Chr(34), ""), ",")
   Wb1.Sheets(sheetName).Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)
Next
```

Hope this works for you.

**Edit: explanation**

> Replace(CH.Range("I2"), Chr(34), "")

will remove the quotationmarks (CHr(34)) in the string in cell I2, by replacing them with "".

> Split(Replace(CH.Range("I2"), Chr(34), ""), ",")

will then return an array of strings (the sheetnames), using "," as the separator.

For the for-each loop to work, the sheetName variable must be declared as an object or a variant and not as a string.

Comment: An explanation of this answer would increase its value.

Comment: I changed your code a bit:
`Dim sheetName As Variant
Set Wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add 'This line will open a new workbook`
I2 now looks like this: FRONTPAGE,AT,DK,ES,IT - no quotes only a comma separating.
When I run the test, I get an error in:
Wb1.Sheets(sheetName).Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)

For Each sheetName In Split(CH.Range("I2"), ",")
   Wb1.Sheets(sheetName).Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)
Next

Comment: Try it without the Replace statement:  For Each sheetName In Split(CH.Range("I2"), ",")

Comment: Already did that in above comment. - I think I'll have some spare time later today to mess about a bit.  Hopefully I can find a  solution.